# Retrieve original message sent to bot

Tags: c#, botframework

We've currently implemented a bot using the Bot Framework and are using BotBuilder.Azure to log messages to an Azure table.

We have multilingual requirements so we're currently detecting the language when a user types in a message and are then translating the messages so that we can send the English version to our English-based NLP.

What's happening now is that our Azure tables have now logged the messages in English instead of in the original language.

We're currently doing the translation within the MessageController class

```
MessageController.cs
...
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity) {
   if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message) {
      activity.Text = DetectAndTranslateActivityText(activity);
   }
}
...
```

Is there a way to log the original text instead of the translated version or is there another recommended approach to translate the messages?

Comment: How did you implement your logging behaviour? With `IActivityLogger`?

Comment: We're currently using the Azure table logger.
`options.Builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(account, defaultBehaviour.ActivitiesTableName));
options.Builder.RegisterType<TableLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();`

Comment: Could you please share us your code of `DetectAndTranslateActivityText`?

Answer (score 0):

LogPostToBot is registered as a keyed type: [DialogModule.cs line 349](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/31048a2173313c81a2db47efce6a8a869b4ec284/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac/Dialogs/DialogModule.cs#L349)

This enables overriding it with a custom implementation:

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(
    builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ActivityLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();

        builder
            .RegisterType<InterceptLogPostToBot>()
            .Keyed<IPostToBot>(typeof(LogPostToBot));

    });

public class InterceptLogPostToBot: IPostToBot
{
    private readonly IPostToBot inner;
    private readonly IActivityLogger logger;
    public InterceptLogPostToBot(IPostToBot inner, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out this.inner, nameof(inner), inner);
        SetField.NotNull(out this.logger, nameof(logger), logger);
    }

    async Task IPostToBot.PostAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        await this.logger.LogAsync(activity);

        //translate here, after the logging is complete

        await inner.PostAsync(activity, token);
    }
}
```